# Why syntax error issue in the below code?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

What is the error in this code?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  
CREATE TABLE dbo.Channel(  
    ChannelID int NULL,  
    ChannelCategoryID int NULL,  
    Channel nvarchar(50) NULL,  
    CreatedDate datetime NULL,  
    CreatedBy nvarchar(255) NULL,  
    ModifiedDate datetime NULL,  
    ModifiedBy nvarchar(255) NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

> Error : Missing right parenthesis

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: This looks like SQL Server, have you TAGGED correctly? There's no missing parenthesis in the SQL you have included so you're not providing the full information.

Comment: @Littlefoot I used Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: @Stu Tagged as in?

Comment: "Oracle SQL Developer" is a GUI tool you used to connect to the database. Which database is it? Oracle? I guess not, that's not Oracle syntax. MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: Yeah, Oracle only.  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: As that looks like SQL Server code, if you are trying to run it on Oracle then that’s probably why it is giving you an error

Answer (score 0):

You are using syntax for SQL Server and not Oracle; they are different RDBMS and have different syntaxes.

In Oracle:

- there is no `datetime` data type, you want `DATE` (which has both date and time components)
- `NVARCHAR` is an alias for `NVARCHAR2`
- `ON [PRIMARY]` is invalid syntax; if you want to specify the tablespace then use `TABLESPACE tablespace_name` but if you want the default tablespace then omit it.
- `GO` is not a valid statement terminator. You want `;` or, on a new line, `/`
- The `SET` commands are not valid in Oracle.

You simply want:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Channel(  
    ChannelID         int            NULL,  
    ChannelCategoryID int            NULL,  
    Channel           nvarchar2(50)  NULL,  
    CreatedDate       DATE           NULL,  
    CreatedBy         nvarchar2(255) NULL,  
    ModifiedDate      DATE           NULL,  
    ModifiedBy        nvarchar2(255) NULL  
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RzBHztYM)